# Using large input files with R Shiny app

Tags: r, csv, shiny

I'm trying to create an app using R's Shiny package that extracts a time series from Fred via Quantmod - somewhat akin to the example using Yahoo (see stockVis at http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson6/).

The thing I want to have though is a list of the series on Fred to choose from. So I'd like the user to be able to specify the time series frequency and the type of seasonal adjustment - rather than have the user guessing the right code.

After a lot of fiddling, I have something that functions, but the problem I have is that it relies on the information file Fred provide in their CSV download, which is large - text file is 36MB.

This takes a very long time to load up and be ready for use in the app. I'm sure there must be better ways to do this that take less time; thus far I've tried `fread()`, `readRDS()`, and most recently attempted to use the `RSQlite` package. None seem to solve the long delay - too long to be practical, although once loaded it works nicely.

Here's the code:
ui.R:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Download Fred Data"),
  sidebarLayout(

sidebarPanel(
  selectInput(
    "freq", "Data Frequency",
    c("Daily" = "D","Weekly" = "W","Bi-Weekly" = "BW","Monthly" = "M",
      "Quarterly" = "Q","Semi-Annual" = "SA","Annual" = "A"),
    selected="Q"),

  selectInput(
    "adj", "Data Adjustment",
    c("Seasonally Adjusted" = "SA","Not Seasonally Adjusted" = "NSA",
      "Seasonally Adjusted Annual Rate" = "SAAR","Smoothed Seasonally Adjusted" = "SSA",
      "Not Applicable" = "NA"),
    selected="SA"),

  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.freq == 'Q' ",
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.adj == 'SA' ",
    selectInput(
      "codeqsa", "Data series",
      c(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="Q" & fred.files$sa=="SA"]),
      selected=head(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="Q" & fred.files$sa=="SA"],1))),
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.adj == 'NSA' ",
                     selectInput(
                       "codeqnsa", "Data series",
                       c(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="Q" & fred.files$sa=="NSA"]),
                       selected=head(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="Q" & fred.files$sa=="NSA"],1))),
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.adj == 'SAAR' ",
                     selectInput(
                       "codeqsaar", "Data series",
                       c(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="Q" & fred.files$sa=="SAAR"]),
                       selected=head(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="Q" & fred.files$sa=="SAAR"],1))),
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.adj == 'SSA' ",
                     selectInput(
                       "codeqssa", "Data series",
                       c(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="Q" & fred.files$sa=="SSA"]),
                       selected=head(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="Q" & fred.files$sa=="SSA"],1))),
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.adj == 'NA' ",
                     selectInput(
                       "codeqna", "Data series",
                       c(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="Q" & fred.files$sa=="NA"]),
                       selected=head(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="Q" & fred.files$sa=="NA"],1)))),
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.freq == 'M' ",
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.adj == 'SA' ",
                     selectInput(
                       "codemsa", "Data series",
                       c(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="M" & fred.files$sa=="SA"]),
                       selected=head(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="M" & fred.files$sa=="SA"],1))),
                     conditionalPanel(condition="input.adj == 'NSA' ",
                                      selectInput(
                                        "codemnsa", "Data series",
                                        c(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="M" & fred.files$sa=="NSA"]),
                                        selected=head(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="M" & fred.files$sa=="NSA"],1))),
                     conditionalPanel(condition="input.adj == 'SAAR' ",
                                      selectInput(
                                        "codemsaar", "Data series",
                                        c(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="M" & fred.files$sa=="SAAR"]),
                                        selected=head(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="M" & fred.files$sa=="SAAR"],1))),
                     conditionalPanel(condition="input.adj == 'SSA' ",
                                      selectInput(
                                        "codemssa", "Data series",
                                        c(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="M" & fred.files$sa=="SSA"]),
                                        selected=head(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="M" & fred.files$sa=="SSA"],1))),
                     conditionalPanel(condition="input.adj == 'NA' ",
                                      selectInput(
                                        "codemna", "Data series",
                                        c(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="M" & fred.files$sa=="NA"]),
                                        selected=head(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="M" & fred.files$sa=="NA"],1)))),
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.freq == 'A' ",
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.adj == 'SA' ",
                     selectInput(
                       "codeasa", "Data series",
                       c(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="A" & fred.files$sa=="SA"]),
                       selected=head(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="A" & fred.files$sa=="SA"],1))),
                     conditionalPanel(condition="input.adj == 'NSA' ",
                                      selectInput(
                                        "codeansa", "Data series",
                                        c(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="A" & fred.files$sa=="NSA"]),
                                        selected=head(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="A" & fred.files$sa=="NSA"],1))),
                     conditionalPanel(condition="input.adj == 'SAAR' ",
                                      selectInput(
                                        "codeasaar", "Data series",
                                        c(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="A" & fred.files$sa=="SAAR"]),
                                        selected=head(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="A" & fred.files$sa=="SAAR"],1))),
                     conditionalPanel(condition="input.adj == 'SSA' ",
                                      selectInput(
                                        "codeassa", "Data series",
                                        c(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="A" & fred.files$sa=="SSA"]),
                                        selected=head(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="A" & fred.files$sa=="SSA"],1))),
                     conditionalPanel(condition="input.adj == 'NA' ",
                                      selectInput(
                                        "codeana", "Data series",
                                        c(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="A" & fred.files$sa=="NA"]),
                                        selected=head(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="A" & fred.files$sa=="NA"],1)))),
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.freq == 'SA' ",
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.adj == 'SA' ",
                     selectInput(
                       "codesasa", "Data series",
                       c(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="SA" & fred.files$sa=="SA"]),
                       selected=head(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="SA" & fred.files$sa=="SA"],1))),
                     conditionalPanel(condition="input.adj == 'NSA' ",
                                      selectInput(
                                        "codesansa", "Data series",
                                        c(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="SA" & fred.files$sa=="NSA"]),
                                        selected=head(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="SA" & fred.files$sa=="NSA"],1))),
                     conditionalPanel(condition="input.adj == 'SAAR' ",
                                      selectInput(
                                        "codesasaar", "Data series",
                                        c(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="SA" & fred.files$sa=="SAAR"]),
                                        selected=head(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="SA" & fred.files$sa=="SAAR"],1))),
                     conditionalPanel(condition="input.adj == 'SSA' ",
                                      selectInput(
                                        "codesassa", "Data series",
                                        c(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="SA" & fred.files$sa=="SSA"]),
                                        selected=head(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="SA" & fred.files$sa=="SSA"],1))),
                     conditionalPanel(condition="input.adj == 'NA' ",
                                      selectInput(
                                        "codesana", "Data series",
                                        c(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="SA" & fred.files$sa=="NA"]),
                                        selected=head(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="SA" & fred.files$sa=="NA"],1)))),
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.freq == 'D' ",
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.adj == 'SA' ",
                     selectInput(
                       "codedsa", "Data series",
                       c(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="D" & fred.files$sa=="SA"]),
                       selected=head(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="D" & fred.files$sa=="SA"],1))),
                     conditionalPanel(condition="input.adj == 'NSA' ",
                                      selectInput(
                                        "codednsa", "Data series",
                                        c(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="D" & fred.files$sa=="NSA"]),
                                        selected=head(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="D" & fred.files$sa=="NSA"],1))),
                     conditionalPanel(condition="input.adj == 'SAAR' ",
                                      selectInput(
                                        "codedsaar", "Data series",
                                        c(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="D" & fred.files$sa=="SAAR"]),
                                        selected=head(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="D" & fred.files$sa=="SAAR"],1))),
                     conditionalPanel(condition="input.adj == 'SSA' ",
                                      selectInput(
                                        "codedssa", "Data series",
                                        c(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="D" & fred.files$sa=="SSA"]),
                                        selected=head(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="D" & fred.files$sa=="SSA"],1))),
                     conditionalPanel(condition="input.adj == 'NA' ",
                                      selectInput(
                                        "codedna", "Data series",
                                        c(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="D" & fred.files$sa=="NA"]),
                                        selected=head(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="D" & fred.files$sa=="NA"],1)))),
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.freq == 'W' ",
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.adj == 'SA' ",
                     selectInput(
                       "codewsa", "Data series",
                       c(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="W" & fred.files$sa=="SA"]),
                       selected=head(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="W" & fred.files$sa=="SA"],1))),
                     conditionalPanel(condition="input.adj == 'NSA' ",
                                      selectInput(
                                        "codewnsa", "Data series",
                                        c(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="W" & fred.files$sa=="NSA"]),
                                        selected=head(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="W" & fred.files$sa=="NSA"],1))),
                     conditionalPanel(condition="input.adj == 'SAAR' ",
                                      selectInput(
                                        "codewsaar", "Data series",
                                        c(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="W" & fred.files$sa=="SAAR"]),
                                        selected=head(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="W" & fred.files$sa=="SAAR"],1))),
                     conditionalPanel(condition="input.adj == 'SSA' ",
                                      selectInput(
                                        "codewssa", "Data series",
                                        c(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="W" & fred.files$sa=="SSA"]),
                                        selected=head(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="W" & fred.files$sa=="SSA"],1))),
                     conditionalPanel(condition="input.adj == 'NA' ",
                                      selectInput(
                                        "codewna", "Data series",
                                        c(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="W" & fred.files$sa=="NA"]),
                                        selected=head(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="W" & fred.files$sa=="NA"],1)))),
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.freq == 'BW' ",
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.adj == 'SA' ",
                     selectInput(
                       "codebwsa", "Data series",
                       c(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="BW" & fred.files$sa=="SA"]),
                       selected=head(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="BW" & fred.files$sa=="SA"],1))),
                     conditionalPanel(condition="input.adj == 'NSA' ",
                                      selectInput(
                                        "codebwnsa", "Data series",
                                        c(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="BW" & fred.files$sa=="NSA"]),
                                        selected=head(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="BW" & fred.files$sa=="NSA"],1))),
                     conditionalPanel(condition="input.adj == 'SAAR' ",
                                      selectInput(
                                        "codebwsaar", "Data series",
                                        c(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="BW" & fred.files$sa=="SAAR"]),
                                        selected=head(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="BW" & fred.files$sa=="SAAR"],1))),
                     conditionalPanel(condition="input.adj == 'SSA' ",
                                      selectInput(
                                        "codebwssa", "Data series",
                                        c(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="BW" & fred.files$sa=="SSA"]),
                                        selected=head(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="BW" & fred.files$sa=="SSA"],1))),
                     conditionalPanel(condition="input.adj == 'NA' ",
                                      selectInput(
                                        "codebwna", "Data series",
                                        c(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="BW" & fred.files$sa=="NA"]),
                                        selected=head(fred.files$desc[fred.files$freq=="BW" & fred.files$sa=="NA"],1))))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("summary"),
      plotOutput('plot')
    )
  )
))
```

server.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(zoo)
library(quantmod)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {  
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    dataset <- new.env()
    list.index <- fred.files[input$freq==fred.files$freq & input$adj==fred.files$sa,]
    if(input$freq=="M" && input$adj=="SA") {fred.code <- input$codemsa}
    if(input$freq=="M" && input$adj=="NSA") {fred.code <- input$codemnsa}
    if(input$freq=="M" && input$adj=="SAAR") {fred.code <- input$codemsaar}
    if(input$freq=="M" && input$adj=="SSA") {fred.code <- input$codemssa}
    if(input$freq=="M" && input$adj=="NA") {fred.code <- input$codemna}
    if(input$freq=="Q" && input$adj=="SA") {fred.code <- input$codeqsa}
    if(input$freq=="Q" && input$adj=="NSA") {fred.code <- input$codeqnsa}
    if(input$freq=="Q" && input$adj=="SAAR") {fred.code <- input$codeqsaar}
    if(input$freq=="Q" && input$adj=="SSA") {fred.code <- input$codeqssa}
    if(input$freq=="Q" && input$adj=="NA") {fred.code <- input$codeqna}
    if(input$freq=="SA" && input$adj=="SA") {fred.code <- input$codesasa}
    if(input$freq=="SA" && input$adj=="NSA") {fred.code <- input$codesansa}
    if(input$freq=="SA" && input$adj=="SAAR") {fred.code <- input$codesasaar}
    if(input$freq=="SA" && input$adj=="SSA") {fred.code <- input$codesassa}
    if(input$freq=="SA" && input$adj=="NA") {fred.code <- input$codesana}
    if(input$freq=="A" && input$adj=="SA") {fred.code <- input$codeasa}
    if(input$freq=="A" && input$adj=="NSA") {fred.code <- input$codeansa}
    if(input$freq=="A" && input$adj=="SAAR") {fred.code <- input$codeasaar}
    if(input$freq=="A" && input$adj=="SSA") {fred.code <- input$codeassa}
    if(input$freq=="A" && input$adj=="NA") {fred.code <- input$codeana}
    if(input$freq=="D" && input$adj=="SA") {fred.code <- input$codedsa}
    if(input$freq=="D" && input$adj=="NSA") {fred.code <- input$codednsa}
    if(input$freq=="D" && input$adj=="SAAR") {fred.code <- input$codedsaar}
    if(input$freq=="D" && input$adj=="SSA") {fred.code <- input$codedssa}
    if(input$freq=="D" && input$adj=="NA") {fred.code <- input$codedna}
    if(input$freq=="W" && input$adj=="SA") {fred.code <- input$codewsa}
    if(input$freq=="W" && input$adj=="NSA") {fred.code <- input$codewnsa}
    if(input$freq=="W" && input$adj=="SAAR") {fred.code <- input$codewsaar}
    if(input$freq=="W" && input$adj=="SSA") {fred.code <- input$codewssa}
    if(input$freq=="W" && input$adj=="NA") {fred.code <- input$codewna}
    if(input$freq=="BW" && input$adj=="SA") {fred.code <- input$codebwsa}
    if(input$freq=="BW" && input$adj=="NSA") {fred.code <- input$codebwnsa}
    if(input$freq=="BW" && input$adj=="SAAR") {fred.code <- input$codebwsaar}
    if(input$freq=="BW" && input$adj=="SSA") {fred.code <- input$codebwssa}
    if(input$freq=="BW" && input$adj=="NA") {fred.code <- input$codebwna}
    data.code <- head(list.index$file[list.index$desc==fred.code & is.na(list.index$desc)==F],1)
    data.series.info <- list.index[list.index$desc==fred.code,]
    getSymbols(data.code,src='FRED',return.class="zoo",env=dataset)
    m <- get(data.code,dataset)
  })

  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    list.index <- fred.files[input$freq==fred.files$freq & input$adj==fred.files$sa,]
    if(input$freq=="M" && input$adj=="SA") {fred.code <- input$codemsa}
    if(input$freq=="M" && input$adj=="NSA") {fred.code <- input$codemnsa}
    if(input$freq=="M" && input$adj=="SAAR") {fred.code <- input$codemsaar}
    if(input$freq=="M" && input$adj=="SSA") {fred.code <- input$codemssa}
    if(input$freq=="M" && input$adj=="NA") {fred.code <- input$codemna}
    if(input$freq=="Q" && input$adj=="SA") {fred.code <- input$codeqsa}
    if(input$freq=="Q" && input$adj=="NSA") {fred.code <- input$codeqnsa}
    if(input$freq=="Q" && input$adj=="SAAR") {fred.code <- input$codeqsaar}
    if(input$freq=="Q" && input$adj=="SSA") {fred.code <- input$codeqssa}
    if(input$freq=="Q" && input$adj=="NA") {fred.code <- input$codeqna}
    if(input$freq=="SA" && input$adj=="SA") {fred.code <- input$codesasa}
    if(input$freq=="SA" && input$adj=="NSA") {fred.code <- input$codesansa}
    if(input$freq=="SA" && input$adj=="SAAR") {fred.code <- input$codesasaar}
    if(input$freq=="SA" && input$adj=="SSA") {fred.code <- input$codesassa}
    if(input$freq=="SA" && input$adj=="NA") {fred.code <- input$codesana}
    if(input$freq=="A" && input$adj=="SA") {fred.code <- input$codeasa}
    if(input$freq=="A" && input$adj=="NSA") {fred.code <- input$codeansa}
    if(input$freq=="A" && input$adj=="SAAR") {fred.code <- input$codeasaar}
    if(input$freq=="A" && input$adj=="SSA") {fred.code <- input$codeassa}
    if(input$freq=="A" && input$adj=="NA") {fred.code <- input$codeana}
    if(input$freq=="D" && input$adj=="SA") {fred.code <- input$codedsa}
    if(input$freq=="D" && input$adj=="NSA") {fred.code <- input$codednsa}
    if(input$freq=="D" && input$adj=="SAAR") {fred.code <- input$codedsaar}
    if(input$freq=="D" && input$adj=="SSA") {fred.code <- input$codedssa}
    if(input$freq=="D" && input$adj=="NA") {fred.code <- input$codedna}
    if(input$freq=="W" && input$adj=="SA") {fred.code <- input$codewsa}
    if(input$freq=="W" && input$adj=="NSA") {fred.code <- input$codewnsa}
    if(input$freq=="W" && input$adj=="SAAR") {fred.code <- input$codewsaar}
    if(input$freq=="W" && input$adj=="SSA") {fred.code <- input$codewssa}
    if(input$freq=="W" && input$adj=="NA") {fred.code <- input$codewna}
    if(input$freq=="BW" && input$adj=="SA") {fred.code <- input$codebwsa}
    if(input$freq=="BW" && input$adj=="NSA") {fred.code <- input$codebwnsa}
    if(input$freq=="BW" && input$adj=="SAAR") {fred.code <- input$codebwsaar}
    if(input$freq=="BW" && input$adj=="SSA") {fred.code <- input$codebwssa}
    if(input$freq=="BW" && input$adj=="NA") {fred.code <- input$codebwna}
    head(list.index[list.index$desc==fred.code,],1)
  })
   output$plot <- renderPlot({
      m <- datasetInput()
      plot(m)
   })

})
```

global.R:

```
fred.files <- read.csv("fred.csv",stringsAsFactors=F)
```

The csv file fred.csv is available at: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0n2rfgya3chiezh/fred.csv?dl=0

It's just a text file with five columns that are used to first filter the selection to choose over, and then to determine the right code to download the Fred data with, and over 200,000 rows.

Happy to accept all tips on all aspects of this, but most pressingly on the issue of time taken to get the app running.